# How can a configure two nodes in one cluster in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, distributed, sense

I have a situation where I have installed two instances of Elasticsearch setup in remote server 1 (node1) and remote server 2 (node2), and I want to connect both these nodes in one cluster, however I also installed the kibana in one server and when I run the GET _cluster/health I get

```
{
"cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
"status" : "green",
"timed_out" : false,
"number_of_nodes" : 1,
"number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
"active_primary_shards" : 1,
"active_shards" : 1,
"relocating_shards" : 0,
"initializing_shards" : 0,
"unassigned_shards" : 0,
"delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
"number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
"number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
"active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

Can you please help while providing any sample for both configs for node1 and node2, and how can I confirm both nodes are added in one cluster.

Below is my elasticsearch.yml file in server 1

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 2
node.name: Server1
path.data: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data
path.logs: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["Server1","Server2"]
network.host: Server1
```

Server2 : elasticsearch.yml file -

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: false
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
node.name: Server2
path.data: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data
path.logs: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["Server1","Server2"]
network.host: Server2
```

Thanks
Gaurav Singh

Comment: If you can provide the logs, that would be helpful to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is formula for minimum master nodes

```
(total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1)
```

So 2 nodes in one cluster is one master node and one is slave node

```
As of formula (2 / 2+1) = 0.6666 ~ 1

discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I also need to put the line in both config and then it worked : discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1

Comment: This is false information. 2 / 2 + 1 is 2.

Answer (score 0):

you configured minimum_master_nodes (discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes) of 2, but the second node have

> node.master: false

either change the second node to master:true or reduce minimum_master_nodes to 1

Answer (score 0):

To help others let me put the both node configuration

Master Node Configuration :

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: true
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 2
node.name: Server1
path.data: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data
path.logs: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["Server1","Server2"]
network.host: Server1
```

Slave Node Configuration :

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: false
cluster.name: elasticsearch
http.port: 9200
node.data: true
node.ingest: true
node.master: false
node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
node.name: Server2
path.data: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\data
path.logs: C:\ProgramData\Elastic\Elasticsearch\logs
transport.tcp.port: 9300
xpack.license.self_generated.type: basic
xpack.security.enabled: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["Server1","Server2"]
network.host: Server2
```

After doing this you will get the response like :

```
{
  "cluster_name": "elasticsearch",
  "status": "green",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 2,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 2,
  "active_primary_shards": 1,
  "active_shards": 2,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 100.0
}
```

Thanks 
Gaurav Singh